# Get single record from the second table if we have duplicates in first three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can you please give me a solution for the below scenario.

I have two tables `employee_name` and `Employee_details`.

Lets think, `Employee_details` table contains multiple years data.  I want to retrieve data from both the tables.

**Table 1: employee_name**

```
emp_no  name    
1       A
2       B
3       C etc..
```

**Table 2: Employee_details**

```
emp_no col1 col2 address salary year  addr_changed_By addr_changed_on  sal_changed_by Sal_changed_on

1      x1   y1   addr1   100000 2013    P            01/12/2014      q              09/12/2014

1      x1   y1   addr2   150000 2014    P            01/12/2014      q              09/12/2014


2      x2   y2   addr4   200000 2014    m            19/12/2014      n              10/12/2014
```

1. I want to get employee details along with name. If first 3 columns
   in the second table having same data then we should get single
   record.
2. Also, I need the data when the record is updated and by whom it is
   updated for each employee record?

Finally, from the above data, I want to get two records like:

```
employee name: A
address : addr1
last updated by: q
last updated on : 09/12/2014

employee name : B
address : addr4
last updated by: m
last updated on : 19/12/2014
```

Comment: Up to this point, what have you tried to get the data you require? If you show us your attempt and show the issues you've had, then we can highlight where and what you are doing wrong and how to fix it. Otherwise, you're simply asking us to write your queries for you and in the process you won't be learning anything.

Comment: Why for `employee : A` last updated by is fetched from `sal_changed_by`  and for `employee : B` it is taken from `addr_changed_By` ??. If you have duplicates in first three columns then how you are considering first row why not second row ?

Comment: we want last updated one and last updated by based on the date. If address is recently updated, then updated by should be addr_changed_by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT emp_no, col1, col2, Changed_On, Changed_By
FROM employee_details ed
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                    CASE WHEN addr_changed_on > Sal_changed_on THEN addr_changed_on ELSE Sal_changed_on END Changed_On,
                    CASE WHEN addr_changed_on > Sal_changed_on THEN addr_changed_By ELSE sal_changed_by END Changed_By
                FROM employee_details ed2
                WHERE emp_no = ed.emp_no 
                    AND col1 = ed.col1
                    AND col2 = ed.col2
                ORDER BY Changed_On DESC) chn
GROUP BY emp_no, col1, col2, Changed_On, Changed_By
```

And tweeking BLAM's code...

```
select last.* 
from 
(
    select emp_no, col1, col2, address, salary, year, Changed_By, Changed_On 
         , row_number() over (partition by emp_no, col1, col2 order by Changed_On desc) as rownum 
      from Employee_details
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN addr_changed_on > Sal_changed_on THEN addr_changed_on ELSE Sal_changed_on END Changed_On,
                            CASE WHEN addr_changed_on > Sal_changed_on THEN addr_changed_By ELSE sal_changed_by END Changed_By) chn
) as last 
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will leave it to you to get the name
This is just salary

```
select last.* 
from 
(
    select temp_no, col1, col2, address, salary, year
         , addr_changed_By, addr_changed_on, sal_changed_by, Sal_changed_on 
         , row_number() over (partition by temp_no, col1, col2 order by Sal_changed_on desc) as rownum 
      from Employee_details
) as last 
where rownum = 1
```